# how to convert nested xml file with multiple namespaces in a soap response into a dataframe using python

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, namespaces, elementtree

Just starting to learn Python. Currently learning to convert a xml file into a dataset, I have no problem to convert xml without namespaces into a dataframe, however, no good luck for xml with multiple namespaces. Any guidance, suggestions would be highly appreciate it.  sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.../envelope/" 
xmlns:a="http://xxxx.com" 
xmlns:d="http://yyy.com/">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <a:item1>
      <a:item2>
        <d:inneritm21>xxx</d:inneritm21>
        <d:inneritm22>yyy</d:inneritm22>
        <d:inneritm23>zzz</d:inneritm23>
        <d:inneritm24>
          <d:inneritm240>
            <d:inneritm241>aa</d:inneritm241>
            <d:inneritm242>bb</d:inneritm242>
            <d:inneritm243>Cc</d:inneritm243>
          </d:inneritm240>
          <d:inneritm240>
            <d:inneritm241>dd</d:inneritm241>
            <d:inneritm242>ee</d:inneritm242>
            <d:inneritm243>ff</d:inneritm243>
          </d:inneritm240>
        </d:inneritm24>
      </a:item2>
      <a:Flag>true</item:Flag>
    </a:item1>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I tried:

```
xml = ET.parse('c:\\myxml.xml')

namespaces={'a':'http://xxxx.com.com',
            'd':'http://yyy.com/'}

with open('c:\\myxml.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    doc = etree.parse(f)
df = []
ws = doc.xpath('.//a:item2', namespaces=namespaces)
if len(ws)>0:
    fc = ws[0].xpath('./d:inneritm24', namespaces=namespaces)
    print(fc)
    for line in fc:
        tmp = []
        cells = line.xpath('.//d:*', namespaces=namespaces)
        for cell in cells:
            print(cell.text)
            tmp.append(cell.text)
        L.append(tmp)
print(df)
```

I couldn't figure out what's wrong, only got empty table. the desired output should be look like:

```
inneritm21  inneritm22  inneritm23  inneritm241 inneritm242 inneritm243
0   xxx yyy zzz aa  bb  cc
1   xxx yyy zzz dd  ee  ff
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Thank you so much for response! I have added desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET, collections
import pandas as pd
d_xml = ET.fromstring(content)[1]
def get_data(d, c = []):
   new_d = collections.defaultdict(list)
   for i in d:
      if not (_c:=list(i)) and not i.tag.endswith('Flag'):
         new_d[0].append((i.tag.split('}')[-1], i.text))
      elif _c:
         new_d[1].append(i)
   if not new_d[1]:
       yield dict(c+new_d[0])
   else:
       for i in new_d[1]:
          yield from get_data(i, c+new_d[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(list(get_data(d_xml)))
```

Output:

```
  inneritm21 inneritm22 inneritm23 inneritm241 inneritm242 inneritm243
0        xxx        yyy        zzz          aa          bb          Cc
1        xxx        yyy        zzz          dd          ee          ff
```